# How not to ignore an item locally which is in .gitignore_global

Tags: git, gitignore

I have `*.log` in .gitignore_global but I want to add it locally.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patterns prefixed with a "!" will match again, so you can add this in your local `.gitignore`:

```
!*.log
```

[From the gitignore docs:](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> - An optional prefix ! which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. If a negated pattern matches, this will override lower precedence patterns sources.